# I receive unexpected internal error when i attempt to parse a JSON string

Tags: java, json, rest

I am attempting to parse the rest response from my Python web server.  I successfully get the string of the JSON content.  To simplify the problem, i am now just trying to parse a test string shown below.

My python test cases parse the string fine, but this is for a java plugin so i am trying to translate it to java.

I have followed a few copies of what appears to be the same examples.

```java
               String inputJSONs = "{\"connections\":[{\"num\":\"1\"},{\"num\":\"2\"}]}";


                System.out.println("testing");
                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(inputJSONs);

                System.out.println("parsed json");
                JSONArray arr = jsono.getJSONArray("connections");

                System.out.println("have arr");
                System.out.println(arr);
```

ERROR o.a.g.rest.RESTExceptionMapper - Unexpected internal error: org/json/JSONObject

I think the plugin framework (apache guacamole) may be hiding some more detailed error, but I can't be sure.

### Adding complete example (removing as much else I could to reproduce)

```java
package org.apache.guacamole.auth;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import java.lang.StringBuilder;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONArray;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import org.apache.guacamole.GuacamoleException;
import org.apache.guacamole.GuacamoleServerException;
import org.apache.guacamole.environment.Environment;
import org.apache.guacamole.environment.LocalEnvironment;
import org.apache.guacamole.net.auth.simple.SimpleAuthenticationProvider;
import org.apache.guacamole.net.auth.Credentials;
import org.apache.guacamole.protocol.GuacamoleConfiguration;

public class RestAuthenticationProvider extends SimpleAuthenticationProvider {

    private final Environment environment;

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestAuthenticationProvider.class.getClass());

    public RestAuthenticationProvider() throws GuacamoleException{
        environment = new LocalEnvironment();
    }

    @Override
    public String getIdentifier() {
        logger.info("====Get Identifier====");
        return "Rest API";
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, GuacamoleConfiguration>
        getAuthorizedConfigurations(Credentials credentials)
            throws GuacamoleException {

            if (credentials.getUsername() == null ){
              return null;
            }

            String inputJSONs = "{\"connections\":[{\"num\":\"1\"},{\"num\":\"2\"}]}";
            System.out.println("testing 2");
            System.out.println(inputJSONs);
            JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(inputJSONs);
            System.out.println("parsed json");
            JSONArray arr = jsono.getJSONArray("connections");
            System.out.println("have arr");
            System.out.println(arr);

            return null;
    }

}
```

Immediately After Logging in the server outputs the following

```
testing 2
{"connections":[{"num":"1"},{"num":"2"}]}
12:00:00.129 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] ERROR o.a.g.rest.RESTExceptionMapper - Unexpected internal error: org/json/JSONObject
```

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem, the code you shared works without any error. Can you please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce your issue?

Comment: hmm, I broke my code out into its own test class, and you are right, it does work just fine.  So that implies it must be   1) something to do with the plugin system,   2) something to do with my larger code.   I will simplify my plugin class and post a more complete example.

Comment: I was able to narrow it down with some help from a Guacamole specific forum.  The final fix was to have maven build a fat jar with the dependencies built in.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to narrow it down with some help from a Guacamole specific forum.  The final fix was to have maven build a fat jar with the dependencies built in.

I added the following to my pom.xml

```xml
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <configuration>
                <!-- get all project dependencies -->
                <descriptorRefs>
<descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <!-- MainClass in mainfest make a executable jar -->
                <archive>
                  <manifest>
<mainClass>com.mkyong.core.utils.App</mainClass>
                  </manifest>
                </archive>

        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
<goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```